# unable to install sonata-admin package in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

when i am installing sonata-admin package into my symfony project. I have configured my yml file as follow:

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.action:
        sonata.block.service.rss:
```

and i hve deps file as follow:

```
[SonataAdminBundle]
    git=git://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sonata/AdminBundle
    version=origin/2.0
```

I am getting the following error

> Installing/Updating SonataAdminBundle
>       a25d8c0e084ed4a175b89a93e93bdea2cf5563ab
>       fatal: Unable to look up github.com (port 9418) (No such host is known. )

```
  [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]

  Cannot import resource "C:\wamp\www\Symfony\app/config\config.yml" from "C:\wa
mp\www\Symfony\app/config/config_dev.yml".




  [InvalidArgumentException]




  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "sonata_block" (in C:
\wamp\www\Symfony\app/config\config.yml). Looked for namespace "sonata_block", f
ound "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine", "ass
etic", "sensio_framework_extra", "jms_security_extra", "acme_hello", "acme_task"
, "ensl_jobeet", "acme_demo", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution"











  [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]

  Cannot import resource "C:\wamp\www\Symfony\app/config\config.yml" from "C:\wa
mp\www\Symfony\app/config/config_dev.yml".











  [InvalidArgumentException]




  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "sonata_block" (in C:
\wamp\www\Symfony\app/config\config.yml). Looked for namespace "sonata_block", f
ound "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine", "ass
etic", "sensio_framework_extra", "jms_security_extra", "acme_hello", "acme_task"
, "ensl_jobeet", "acme_demo", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution"
```

what should I do in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to install your vendors it seems that it cannot contact with github.com with the git: protocol, that is why it is saying that it cannot contact using the 9418 port, which is the port that the git protocol uses. This may be due to some firewall blocking this port or any similar reason. Since it cannot download the SonataAdmin code that is why you get all the other errors.

What you can do is replace the git: protocol with the http: protocol which can be used to access github as well. So just change your deps to:

```
[SonataAdminBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sonata/AdminBundle
    version=origin/2.0
```

and it should work